# Access VBA collection item by variable - Mac Excel 2011

Tags: vba, excel

I have a collection called kvs which contains an entry firstname:john. If I access the collection by kvs("firstname") I get john back as expected.

However, I'm trying to access this entry through a variable x (a string) which is currently:

```
print x
firstname
```

kvs(x) returns a subscript out of range error entered as:

```
print kvs(x)
```

as it does if it's set so:

```
print x
"firstname"
```

How can I access an item in my collection through a variable? I don't know what the collection fields are beforehand so can't hardcode them in.

Comment: Did you check that `firstname` is stored into `x`?

Comment: See above where I put the output of "print x", both with firstname and "firstname"

Comment: This works as expected when I try it...

Comment: Also this is on Mac Excel 2011

Comment: Can you revise to show actual, working code instead of pseudocode? Use a simple test case and exhibit the error. My bet is that @findwindow has correctly diagnosed the problem...

Comment: Oh. Those are `debug.prints`? Can you use a `dictionary` instead?

Comment: Consider re-phrasing title as *Access VBA* can refer to the VBA object library of MS Access, the database Office sibling to Excel though only available on Windows. In fact, `access-vba` is a SO tag.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Public Sub collectionUsingVarAsKey()
    Set kvs = New Collection
    Dim key As String
    kvs.Add "John", "firstname"
    key = "firstname"
    Debug.Print kvs(key)
End Sub
```

Have you actually added the value "John" using the key "firstname" to the collection?